# Sqlite (ADO) and Windows 2000

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

I'm trying to get SQLite to work on W2K SP4. It always crashes with an nothing saying Windows Message:

"****.exe has generated errors and will be closed by Windows. You will need to restart the programm ... An error log is being created."

This happens every time the program wants to access the System.Data.SQLite.dll, I also tried some mods on the System.Data.SQLite.dll.config with no success.

I tried different binarys of sqlite without success. Load the sqlite core form nuget the sqlite3 binary and nothing is working.

My suggestion is that is has to do with the "preload feature" of the lib.

I'm using VS2017 with .net 2 as target framework, target plattform is x86 (don't know if this matters), also tried it with VS2010, same issues.

I hope anyone can help me to solve this

kind regards

Comment: Are you in debug or release? If release, is the binary being moved to another place? I had issues with SQLite while moving binary to a different folder, it was because `SQLite.Interop.dll` was not found. The workaround was to retain the folder structure and all files, or use Fody to embed the dlls. If it's not your case, hope others could help, I don't know.

Comment: I'll moved it from my dev maschine to the target enviroment. But the structure is left as VS created it. If i run it the the db file gets created but then exits with the message above. If I run it from dev maschine over network. it works :S

Comment: If it works in IDE but not on target machines, then you may need to look into the dependencies. If it doesn't work in IDE, maybe you need to check your code. Try to create a minimum working database with very simple structure to find and test the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occured in my case (Windows 2000 SP4, C++ application with SQLite 3.19.1, amalgamation). The cause was in usage of function rand_s() by SQLite. SQLite 3.12 and newer uses rand_s in winRandomness() implementation. rand_s() depends on RtlGenRandom, which is only available in Windows XP and later. Please try to use System.Data.SQLite.dll 1.0.99.1 (SQLite 3.9.3) or earlier.

Downloads page for 1.0.99:

https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/094463a49b6d027c